# nginx reverse proxy - route traffic on location part

Tags: nginx, proxy, routes, location, reverse

I want to route traffic within Nginx reverse proxy solution. I need to pass traffic for "/" to one server (docker container) and "/other_place" to other server (docker container). However my following solution seems to be not working at all. I just can't understand why...

What do I need to pass/change and how? I am trying to understand Nginx upstream and location directives, but somehow feel lost...

{

```
{ 
upstream A.B.C.com
server 172.17.0.5:80;   
server 172.17.0.8:80;
}

{
server
limit_conn perip 50;
limit_req zone=persec burst=80 nodelay;
server_name A.B.C.com; 

location / {
        proxy_pass http://A.B.C.com; 
}
location /other_place {
        proxy_pass http://A.B.C.com;
}
```

}

For explanation: I am using the reverse nginx proxy solution based on this project/article: http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2014/03/25/automated-nginx-reverse-proxy-for-docker/. I know how to adjust nginx template file to get nginx configuration generated based on my needs.

My trouble is that when anything comes to **/some** it is correctly routed to first server -> to "/", but when there's a traffic for "**/other_place**", then it goes to "/" -> to first server, not to the one handling "/other_place".

Thanks in advance for your precious time and patience with me.

Comment: try to reverse the position of locations, first the /other_place, then the root /

Comment: well, I tried this, it's not working...